# When I try to draw polygons why am I losing vertices?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

When I try to draw polygons why am I losing vertices? I'm delineating stream terraces on some large DEMs but have clipped the data frame to an area of around 3 X 8 km. I want to be able to create vertices that are as close as 5 meters on the ground.

I adjusted the snapping tolerance but that didn't work. Must be the x,y tolerance of my layers. Should have mentioned I'm using both 10m and 1m DEMs. Guessing then that the 10m DEM is simplifying my small polygons. Do I join/relate the 10m and 1m DEMs?

Comment: perhaps this has to do with the snapping tolerance you have set? Go to options in your Snapping toolbar, and reduce the number for tolerance

Comment: Yeah, could be snapping, or even the underlying XY resolution and tolerance of your feature class/shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a workaround.... Guess I'll just make my smaller polygons on a new map using just the 1 meter LiDAR DEM, then add them to the 10m and 1m DEM composite map. Wish I had 1 meter coverage for the whole project!